# The type or namespace name 'PrintDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I had an old Windows Form App with this code:

```
public static void PrintTheNumber(int numberOfLabels, string toPrint)
{
    PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
    p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
    {
        e1.Graphics.DrawString(toPrint, new Font("Times New Roman", 12),
            new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
            new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
    };

    try
    {
        p.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)numberOfLabels;
        p.Print();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Printer error!");
    }
}
```

And now I am converting it to WPF and I get exactly this error from my question.

I am stuck and don't know how to print now with WPF. If anyone could explain it to me what is the problem?

I just want to print a string on a click of a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.7.1).

That class is defined in System.Drawing.dll; you need to add a reference to that assembly (and include the namespace).

[image]
[image]

And then you can just import it at the top of your class like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

Comment: True... I googled and found the answer...But on that page it is not explained well. I will edit and accept your answer and make it good so that anyone can understand it!